# Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, canvas, range

I've work with canvas in the past with javascript. I've put together a project to get my feet wet with canvas in react. I am creating a fractal tree. The tree can be controlled by ranges for Right Angle and Left Angle, and Right Length and Left Length. There is also a checkbox that gives the tree leaves or removes them.

In regards to using canvas in react i have a question regarding getContext('2d'). I am receiving an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

canvas.getContext('2d') is assigned to ctx in useEffects. I need to access ctx in other methods. How do i make ctx accessible ?

```
export default function App() {

  const [rightAngleValue, setAngleRightValue] = useState(11);
  const [leftAngleValue, setAngleLeftValue] = useState(4.5);
  const [leftLengthValue, setLeftLengthValue] = useState(0.65);
  const [rightLengthValue, setRightLengthValue] = useState(0.75);

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

const handleRightAngleChange = e => {
  const angleRight = e.currentTarget.value
  setAngleRightValue(angleRight);
}

const handleLeftAngleChange = e => {
  const angleLeft = e.currentTarget.value
  setAngleLeftValue(angleLeft);
}

const handleRightLengthChange = e => {
  const rightLength = e.currentTarget.value
  setRightLengthValue(rightLength)
}

const handleLeftLengthChange = e => {
  const leftLength = e.currentTarget.value
  setLeftLengthValue(leftLength)
}

useEffect(() => {

  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  const centerX = canvas.width / 2
  const bottom = canvas.height
  let startLength = 100
})


  return (
     <Container>

       <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="800" height="400"/>

       <Form action="">
         <FormItem >
           <FormLabel htmlFor="angleRight">Right Angle</FormLabel>

           <input type="range" name="angleRight"  min="3" max="15"
                  value={rightAngleValue} step="0.1" onChange = {handleRightAngleChange}/>

           <FormLabel htmlFor="angleLeft">Left Angle</FormLabel>

           <input type="range" name="angleLeft" min="3" max="15"
                  value={leftAngleValue} step="0.1" onChange={handleLeftAngleChange}/>
         </FormItem>

         <FormItem>
           <FormLabel htmlFor="lengthRight">Right Length</FormLabel>

           <input type="range" name="lengthRight" min="0.63"
                  max="0.75" value={rightLengthValue} onChange={handleRightLengthChange} step="0.01"/>

           <FormLabel htmlFor="lengthLeft">Left Length</FormLabel>

           <input type="range" name="lengthLeft" min="0.63"
                  max="0.75" value={leftLengthValue} onChange={handleLeftLengthChange} step="0.01"/>
         </FormItem>

         <FormItem>
           <FormLabel htmlFor="leaves">Drawing leaves?</FormLabel>
           <input type="checkbox" name="leaves" checked="true"/>
         </FormItem>

       </Form>

     </Container>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ref for storing context and use the value in other functions

```
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const ctx = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    ctx.current = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }, []);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-aryabhata-3y1pk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

React official doc says: **"We didn’t choose useRef in this example because an object ref doesn’t notify us about changes to the current ref value."**

Instead of `useRef` you should create callback with `useCallback`.

```
  const setCanvasRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
     // logic you need
    }
  }, []);

  ...
      <canvas ref={setCanvasRef} width="800" height="400"/>
  ...
```

I hope this will help you to figure out [Ref objects inside useEffect Hooks](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780)